# Resistors in parallel: How do I make this rigorous?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

In my revision guide it says "when two resistors are in parallel, the current has two paths it can flow through so there is less opposition to the current. This is why the combined resistance is less than the separate resistances."

This is of course a true statement, because $R_{combined}=\frac{R_1\times R_2}{R_1+R_2}<R_1$ $\Leftrightarrow \frac{R_2}{R_1+R_2}<1$ $\Leftrightarrow R_2<R_1+R_2$ (and similarly for $R_2$). However, it is also vague in the sense that I couldn't imagine someone using it to discover that the separate resistances in parallel are less than the combined resistance, without doing any maths.

Basically, it is what Dirac said about philosophy: It creates good explanations for things that have already been discovered, but cannot be used to discover NEW laws.

But I was wondering if we can make the explanation rigorous enough so that it becomes a correct explanation even without knowing it before-hand.

I don't think it's possible to keep it as simple and intuitive as "current has less opposition so resistance is less" while increasing the rigor.

Comment: What can't you imagine about someone doing an experiment with two resistors? Maybe you should be thinking less about what Dirac said and learn the definition of science, first?

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual question is. The "rigorous" statement is to write down the formulae, the qualitative statement is that what your revision guide says. What's the question about that?

Comment: @CuriousOne: Dirac is my idol, I will never stop thinking about what he said. But yes, experiments would work, it's just that when you try to explain them qualitatively it isn't rigorous enough. How do you make "less opposition to the current" rigorous while keeping it qualitative and as intuitive?

Comment: You really need to stop idolizing Dirac before you understand what he actually did. At this point you simply fail to show any insight into what the word "science" means. There is no such thing as "rigorous" in science, and that's even more pronounced in physics. Physics is the art of approximation. As my first year theory teacher told us "Everybody who can't live with that should leave the room now.". Can you live with that?

Comment: @CuriousOne: I don't think I can. I like to approach it from as rigorous a perspective as possible. And while I don't understand what Dirac did (I started high school this year, can't really be expected to know complex analysis and whatnot) I am aware that he encouraged the use of pure mathematics in the future of physics, and to stop doing experiments. He predicted antimatter without any experiments. (In short, I would probably change to a mathematics course if for whatever reason found myself in that room.)

Comment: And off to the mathematics department you go. There you can meet Mr. Goedel who has proven rigorously that you will never be able to prove most non-trivial propositions. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne: You got me there, but again anything related to physics is probably too natural to be one of those propositions so I can live with that. The area I dream of studying (the relation of quantum physics with number theory -- Riemann Hypothesis, etc.) is natural enough to not suffer from Godel.

Comment: Good luck with your plans.

Comment: @user45220: I wouldn't be surprised if Gödel would crop up there. It is precisely in number theory, where his statements were derived... Also, there are results about undecidability questions in mathematical physics such as this one http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.04573. Obviously, if it really occurs in nature, you will always be able to decide the outcome...

Answer (score 3):

Resistance is Voltage per Current. $R = V/I$ or $V = RI$ if you like.

So if you put two resistors in series, the voltage is that due to the first, plus that due to the second.
You understand that perfectly.

Now, what is the inverse of Resistance, Current per Voltage?
Give it a name, call it Conductance, perhaps. $C = 1/R = I/V$
Then $I = CV$ if you like.

OK, put two resistors in parallel, and what is the conductance?
It is that due to the first resistor, plus that due to the second.
So convert back to $R$ and you have your answer.

So for example, if you have two resistors $R_1$ and $R_2$, their conductances are $1/R_1$ and $1/R_2$, right?
Now put them in parallel - the conductances add, right?
So the total conductance is $1/R_1 + 1/R_2$.
So what's the combined resistance? One over that, or $1/(1/R_1 + 1/R_2)$.

You can put numbers on it if you like, but why is the combined resistance less than either resistor?
Because the combined conductance is *more*.

Comment: When I read the question, this was the answer that formed in my head. You might just add a couple of lines of math to show how this intuitive and rigorous approach works back to the expression OP is familiar with.

Answer (score 3):

It perhaps is not as rigorous as you want, but it is simple and intuitive:
$$
R = \frac{\rho L}{A}
$$

Where $\rho$ is the resistivity, $L$ is the length, $A$ is the cross-section area. When you plug resistances in series, you "are" increasing $L$, and thus $R$ increases. If you put in parallel, you "are" increasing $A$, and thus $R$ decreases.