# Why does the resistance halve when two resistors of equal resistance are in parallel?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image]

This is the question and answer to a homework question and I do not understand why this is the case. What is the logic behind it?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/183845/2451

Answer (score 3):

Use kirchhoff's first law, so for two resistors in parallel:

$$
I_\text{total}=I_1+I_2
$$
Then just use I=V/R
$$
\\\frac{V}{R_\text{total}}=\frac{V}{R_1}+\frac{V}{R_2}
$$

The voltage across any component, whether it be across resistor 1, 2, or the whole parallel portion of the circuit, is the same. It just cancels out so you can divide both sides by V.

Answer (score 2):

This is more intuitive if you think in terms of *conductance*, which is the inverse of resistance (1/R). When you put two equal resistors in parallel, you double the overall conductance. Why? You are adding a second path for current to flow, so you double that flow.

Unfortunately, we tend to speak mostly in terms of resistance, which makes the math a bit messier in your case. But at least this gives you a conceptual explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Two identical hoses with the same pressure difference between their ends will carry twice as much water as each does individually. So you get twice as much flow (current) for the same pressure difference (voltage), which is another intuitive way of thinking about [Dave's Answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/184764/26076) that it is more enlightening in this case to think in terms of *conductances* rather than resistances.

Note that fluids, hoses and pressure differences are a completely valid way of thinking about circuits as long as the frequency is not high enough to make electrodynamic effects important (*i.e.* the wavelength corresponding to the frequency is large compared to the size of the circuit). This is because the continuity equation for charge is precisely the same as that for an incompressible fluid, and so the mathematical analogy is sound.

Comment: "Dan's amswer"?? Did you mean "Dave's answer"? Explanation of hose analogy is a good one.